# Azure Service Bus topics partitioning

Tags: .net, azure, messaging, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm trying to send a message to a topic which was created with both **Enable duplicate detection** and **Enable partitioning** options checked. I do not set `SessionId` and `PartitionKey` properties on my `BrokeredMessage` instance. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning):

> If the queue or topic has the
>   QueueDescription.RequiresDuplicateDetection property set to true and
>   the BrokeredMessage.SessionId or BrokeredMessage.PartitionKey
>   properties are not set, then the BrokeredMessage.MessageId property
>   serves as the partition key.

After I create an instance of `BrokeredMessage` its `MessageId` property is initialized automatically so I expect partitioning to work. But it does not:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception
>   while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage2Async --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: SessionId needs to be set for all
>   brokered messages to a Partitioned Topic that supports Ordering, Topic
>   Name = dev1-mtapp:Topic:response-topic~255.
>   TrackingId:5fbe5df2-8747-4053-ba79-c29a80e9d1ed_G25_B31,
>   SystemTracker:dev1-mtapp:topic:response-topic~255

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set:
 `topicDescription.SupportOrdering = false.` 
For example:

```
        if (!this.namespaceManager.TopicExists(topicName))
        {
            TopicDescription topicDescription = new TopicDescription(topicName);
            topicDescription.SupportOrdering = false;
            this.namespaceManager.CreateTopic(topicDescription);
        }
```

Comment: How do I set via the portal? I can't see anything related on the topic create screen.

Comment: It's probably not possible. May be in Visual Studio. You can uncheck "Enable partitioning" via portal. This can help.

Comment: Thank you! Can confirm that works and **Enforce Message Ordering** flag can be checked/unchecked in Service Bus Explorer (no need to recreate a topic).