# Azure Service bus with AMQP - how to specify the session ID

Tags: java, azure, session, amqp, azureservicebus

I am trying to send messages to Service bus using AMQP QPID java library

I am getting this error:

> "SessionId needs to be set for all brokered messages to a Partitioned
>   Topic that supports Ordering"

My topic has "Enforce Message ordering" turned on  (this is way i get this error i guess)

When using the Azure Service bus java library (and not AMQP) i have this function :

> this.entity.setSessionId(...);

When using the AMQP library i do not see an option to set the session ID on the message i want to send

Note that if i un-check the option "Enforce Message ordering" the message will be sent successfully

This is my code

```
private boolean sendServiceBusMsg(MessageProducer sender,Session sendSession) {

        try {
            // generate message

            BytesMessage createBytesMessage = (BytesMessage)sendSession.createBytesMessage();

            createBytesMessage.setStringProperty(CAMPAIGN_ID, campaignKey);             
            createBytesMessage.setJMSMessageID("ID:" + bm.getMessageId());                                                    
      createBytesMessage.setContentType(Symbol.getSymbol("application/octet-stream"));

            /*message is the actual data i send / not seen here*/
            createBytesMessage.writeBytes(message.toByteArray());

            sender.send(createBytesMessage);

        } catch (JMSException e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SessionId property is mapped to AMQP message properties.group-id. The Qpid JMS client should map it to JMSXGroupID property, so try the following,

`createBytesMessage.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", "session-1");`

Comment: Is there any way that we can specify the groupID for the consumer? As if sessions are enabled on Azure Service Bus queue then the consumer needs to be a session based consumer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed, there is a similar SO thread [Azure Service Bus topics partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845716/azure-service-bus-topics-partitioning) verified that to disable the feature `Enforce Message Ordering` via set  `SupportOrdering` with `false` can solve the issue, but it can't be done via Azure Service Bus Java library because the property [`supportsOrdering`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/8ee16218d87730e699599db9d184ef014247ef6f/azure-servicebus/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/management/TopicDescription.java#L21) is privated now.

And you can try to set property `Group` as @XinChen said using AMQP, as the content below from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/e237b5aa298e762c2a7322cbb233c3a431302205/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/IMessageSession.java#L14).

> Service Bus Sessions, also called '**Groups**' in the AMQP 1.0 protocol, are unbounded sequences of related messages. ServiceBus guarantees ordering of messages in a session.

Hope it helps.