# Sending Session-Enabled messages to Premium-Tier Service Bus doesn't work

Tags: java, azure, servicebus

I'm using com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms:4.7.0 to send messages to queues in Azure Service Bus, using the Spring JmsTemplate, Spring Boot version 2.6.8. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402822/azure-service-bus-with-amqp-how-to-specify-the-session-id) you need to set the JMSXGroupID property on the message, in order to send it to a queue that has sessions enabled.

I do exactly that and when I send the message to a queue in a standard-tier Service Bus it works just fine.

When the same code is used to send requests to a premium-tier Service Bus, I get the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProviderException: The SessionId was not set on a message, and it cannot be sent to the entity. Entities that have session support enabled can only receive messages that have the SessionId set to a valid value. Reference:b555fb0f-abef-4c8e-a1e3-16f3040ef2a0, TrackingId:ae38db690000043a00056bc2647dfc26_G5S1_B22S1, SystemTracker:queuenamehere, Timestamp:2023-06-05T15:15:50 [condition = amqp:not-allowed] at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpSupport.convertToNonFatalException(AmqpSupport.java:181) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar:na] at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpFixedProducer.applyDeliveryStateUpdate(AmqpFixedProducer.java:252) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar:na] at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpFixedProducer.processDeliveryUpdates(AmqpFixedProducer.java:223) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar:na]
```

The queues and the Service Bus resources are created via a terraform script, to make sure everything is exactly the same.

What I would expect is my app to be able to send messages to a session-enabled queue on a premium-tier Service Bus. I also did some debugging and made sure that the property is actually set on the outgoing message.

I have a message producer bean which has the following method (the jmsTemplate is autowired):

```
private void sendMessageToQueue(Queue queue, Object payload, boolean setGroupId)
{
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, payload, (Message message) ->
    {
        if (setGroupId)
        {
            setGroupId(message);
        }
        return message;
    });
}
```

The setGroupId method looks as follows:

```
void setGroupId(Message message)
{
    try
    {
        message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID","0");
    }
    catch (JMSException e)
    {
        LOG.error("Setting of JMSXGroupID failed with exception: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code in the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with the SDK. Setting the pricing-tier parameter in the yml file to 'standard' instead of 'premium' "fixed" the issue.